# ClassInitialize not working Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I try to make initial for each class e.q

1. open new browser window with link X for first class1 , make all tests then close browser, 

2. open new browser window with link X for second class2 , make all tests then close browser,

When use ClassInitialize it is not openning url at the beginning

```
public static void Initialize(){
_webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
}


     [TestClass]
public class TestBase
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Browser.Initialize();
        Pages.Login.Login();
    }

    [ClassCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        Browser.Close();
        Browser.Quit();
    }
```

I don't know what does really mean 'TestContext context', 
What should I put in here? Mabye here is a problem

```
[ClassInitialize()]
        public static void ClassInit(**TestContext context**)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ClassInit " **+ context.TestName**);
        }
```

When I make TestInitialize it's working

```
 public class TestBase
{

    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeEach()
    {
        Browser.Initialize();
    }
    [TestCleanup]
    public void CleanupTestEach()
    {
        Browser.Close();
        Browser.Quit();

    }
}
```

TestClass1

```
[TestClass]
public class ValidUserCanSuccesfullyLogIn : TestBase 
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void RunTest()
    {

       PagesTest.Login.GoTo();
       PagesTest.Login.Login("login", "pass");
       Assert.IsTrue(PagesTest.MyMembership.IsAt(), " A valid user was not able to successfully login");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx) ClassInitialize method must have this signature

`public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)`

You don't call this function by yourself, and in your case, you don't have to do anything with `context` parameter.

Comment: ok thanks, I have changed to 'public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)' but it still not working

Comment: https://github.com/elkostek/QA/tree/master/Selenium -here I add my project

Comment: Init and cleanup method must be in test class not in father class. I create a pull request to your github repo.

Comment: Thank you, why that clean and init method must be in test class , is any other way to put only in TestBase some method to initialize during test every class?  I have started try nUnit to fixe this

Comment: one more question for your sollution, when I have uncomment Close() and Quit() the second test faild

      [TestCleanup]
            public void Cleanup()
            {
                Browser.Close();
                Browser.Quit();
            }

Have you got any idea how to soved this